# Bootstrap Z-index Image not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can with bootstrap using z-index to center the image at the middle and look like this image at pc phone and tablet without any problem?

[image]

```
.imglogo{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    width: 300px;
}

 <div class="row">
     <img src="img/logo%20corner.png" class="center-block img-responsive imglogo">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned that you're using `<img>` tags to make a background image. Why not simply add as my example:

```css
    body {
        background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Gingerbread_House_Essex_CT.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 style="color:white;">TEXT OR MENU HERE</h1>
</body>
```

I added a little bit of styling to mine just so you can see the text but why not follow this initial setup instead of referring to `<img>` and then z-indexing the image to the back.

NOTE: You don't have to run this as the `body` tag, you can run it under any class or ID you want to.